# Windows Phone 8 XAP file hacked, patched, bypass Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

About 1 month ago, I see my app (xap file) hacked and published on too many sites that distribute XAP for windows phone 8, if you download the XAP from windows store, you can't unzip it's content, but When I download the xap from hacked sites, I can unzip and refactor the code! and the app bypass windows store then the user can use it without paying its price!

When I started WP8 dev. I heard that WP7 can be hacked but WP8 cannot!,

Its too frustrating, is WP8 hacked now?

Thanks

Comment: Everything can be hacked, given local hardware and enough time.

Comment: Thanks Michael, yes this is a generic answer, but from you exp. do you think WP8 Certificate NOW is hacked?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there were a couple of older (non-Nokia) Windows Phone 8 devices that were rooted. I think one was one of the older Samsung phones. Anyways, because they rooted it, you are able to copy the contents of the XAP files from a device unencrypted and view their contents. It sucks but there is not a lot that can be done about it.

The good news is a) You can only install these XAPs on other rooted or developer-unlocked phones, and b) all Windows Phone 8 devices will be upgraded to Windows Phone 8.1 this year, which uses a new packaging format (mitigating the issue somewhat).

HTH